# RavenDB Errors with NServiceBus 4.0

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I've downloaded and installed NServiceBus 4.0, but I'm having some difficulty when the bus starts up...

2013-09-18 15:53:40,887 [1] WARN  NServiceBus.Persistence.Raven.RavenUserInstall
    er [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to add user to raven. Processing will continue
    System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Raven.Abstractions.Data.PutRes
    ult Raven.Client.Connection.IDatabaseCommands.Put(System.String, System.Nullable
    `1, Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject, Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject)'.
       at NServiceBus.Persistence.Raven.RavenUserInstaller.AddUserToDatabase(String
    identity, DocumentStore documentStore)
       at NServiceBus.Persistence.Raven.RavenUserInstaller.Install(String identity)
    in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Persistence\Raven\Ra
    venUserInstaller.cs:line 40

also when I try to persist changes to the document store...

```
 public class RavenUnitOfWork: IManageUnitsOfWork
    {
        public IDocumentSession Session { get; set; }
        public void Begin()
        {

        }

        public void End(Exception ex = null)
        {
            if (ex == null && Session != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Saving Changes to DB.");
                 Session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

produces


    2013-09-18 15:57:38,007 [13] INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiv
    er [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to process message
    System.InvalidOperationException: Url: "/bulk_docs"

    System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xx
    xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
       at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failure
    MessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exce
    ption innerException)
       at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithDashes(String guidString, GuidResult& result)
       at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
       at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
       at Raven.Database.Server.AbstractRequestResponder.GetRequestTransaction(IHttp
    Context context)
       at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Respond(IHttpContext contex
    t)
       at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx)
       at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx)
     ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Intern
    al Server Error.
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getRespons
    e) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonReque
    st.cs:line 340
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMe
    ssage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unica
    st\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 357
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessag
    e message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\T
    ransport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 235
       at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.ProcessMessage(TransportMe
    ssage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Trans
    ports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 262
       at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in c:\BuildAgent\
    work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.c
    s:line 197
    2013-09-18 15:57:38,129 [29] INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiv
    er [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to process message
    System.InvalidOperationException: Url: "/bulk_docs"

    System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xx
    xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
       at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failure
    MessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exce
    ption innerException)
       at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithDashes(String guidString, GuidResult& result)
       at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
       at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
       at Raven.Database.Server.AbstractRequestResponder.GetRequestTransaction(IHttp
    Context context)
       at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Respond(IHttpContext contex
    t)
       at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx)
       at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx)
     ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Intern
    al Server Error.
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getRespons
    e) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonReque
    st.cs:line 340
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMe
    ssage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unica
    st\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 357
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessag
    e message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\T
    ransport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 235
       at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.ProcessMessage(TransportMe
    ssage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Trans
    ports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 262
       at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in c:\BuildAgent\
    work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.c
    s:line 197
    2013-09-18 15:57:38,262 [30] INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiv
    er [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to process message
    System.InvalidOperationException: Url: "/bulk_docs"
```

I've configured Raven as follows:

```
   Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentStore>(() =>
            {
                var store = new DocumentStore
                    {
                        Url = "" // <-- Points to my machine at port 8080
                    };
                store.Initialize();
                store.JsonRequestFactory.DisableRequestCompression = true;
                return store;
            }, DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);

        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentSession>(() => { return Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession(); }, DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork);
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<RavenUnitOfWork>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork);
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 5):

It's a known issue.  See [#1518](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1518).  It's been fixed in [#1551](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/pull/1551), but hasn't yet made it into a release.  Either try building yourself from source, or wait for it to be included in a release.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev - Please report the issue to the NSB team for verification.  Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by adding RavenDb.Client v2 to my solution. I used 2.5 before since I use RavenDb within the project. For me this means that in any project that references NSB it is impossible to use the latest RavenDb.Client assembly for your own purpose.

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are running Raven v2.
Raven v2.5 has not been tested against NServiceBus v4!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the `MissingMethodException` I was getting when using Raven Client 2.5 and NServiceBus 4.4.2 by adding an assembly binding redirect

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Raven.Client.Lightweight" publicKeyToken="37f41c7f99471593" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```