# Why my NService Bus can send command but not publish event?

Tags: nservicebus

I have an web application using NService Bus to send message and another application consume messages. The web app can send commands to the bus successfully and consumer handles commands well. But the web app cannot publish any events to the bus. When call Bus.Publish(new TestEvent()), no message in the queue. In the localhost:8080 database for the publisher, there is no subscription record neither. What's possibly wrong?
Here is my bus init:

```
Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName("LtssServiceHostNew")
            .StructureMapBuilder(container)
            .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("eltss.Message") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"))
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("eltss.Message") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"))
            .UseTransport<Msmq>()
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
```

Comment: this looks like it will result in a conversation to help you troubleshoot. i suggest you move the question to the forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware

Comment: this user is asking for help troubleshooting their specific issue. a conversation will need to take place to derive the problem. it is unlikely that any one question will be helpful to another user viewing this answer

Comment: You need to configure a subscription storage http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/publish-subscribe-configuration

Comment: It looks like the RavenDb version in NServiceBus is 2.0.3 has issues with RavenDb version 2.5.7 in our projects. It fails to write the subscription into the subscription storage. There is no problem to write subscription storage if run a plain project without RavenDB. Anybody has the same issue?

Comment: It turns out that NService Bus cannot work with RavenDB 2.5. I have to  modify NServiceBus to use RavenDB 2.5. Others have the same issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881420/ravendb-errors-with-nservicebus-4-0.